# SQL Server 2017 log file growth with memory optimized table

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, sql-server-2017, memory-optimized-tables

I'm start to using the memory optimized table, the problem that I have is the log file growth also with the database put in simple mode.

On my maintenance schedule I checkpoint and shrink, but still has the issue. If I revert back the tables to normal disk table, everything looks fine.

Did somebody know the reason?

The database has the column `LOG_REUSE_WAIT_DESC` to 'nothing' in `sys.databases`.

All the mem opt tables are in SCHEMA_ONLY modality, but still full logging.

SQL Server 2017 version 14.0.3037

I also see these messages in the SQL Server error log:

> spid38s,Unknown,[INFO] Database ID: [5]. Deleting unrecoverable checkpoint table row (id: 669)
>   spid102,Unknown,[INFO] HkHostFreezeCkptTrimming(). Database ID: [5]. HkTrimLSN Frozen: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWldc.png)
>   spid102,Unknown,[INFO] getMaxUnrecoverableCheckpointId(). Database ID: [5]. Start of Log LSN: 00001714:000004E0:0002 used to trim unrecoverable checkpoint files tables during full backup

Sizes situation with memory optimized tables: 
[image: Memory optimized table]

Sizes situation with disk based table:
[image: Disk based table]

Comment: @AlbertoCigliutti Please add new information to the question instead of in comments. There is an [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/216982/edit) link that allows you to do so.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, if you use durable memory-optimized tables, everything from the memory-optimized side will be fully logged - the database recovery setting is not respected.

Next, is your 2017 install fully patched? There have been a number of fixes to the In-Memory engine since RTM.

In order for the log to be cleared of memory-optimized transactions, they must also be written to the checkpoint file pairs. If the CFPs needed to be expanded/added, and the drive/volume that hosts them can't do that, then the transaction log cannot be cleared.

Comment: I would open a ticket with Microsoft, and/or post on the MSDN In-Memory forum

Comment: @jadarnel27 is correct - I should have written: "If I was you, I would open a ticket with Microsoft, and/or post on the MSDN In-Memory forum".